# Plotting uncertainty incorrectly resulting a weird graph

Tags: r, syntax, mixed-models, linearmodels, uncertainty

I am trying to plot a model output and two confidence intervals but  I am getting some weird graphs and I do not understand what I have done wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtPty.png)

My code :

```
#plotting model with uncertainity
#need to create Confidence intervals
model4.pred2<-predict(model4,newdata=data,interval="confidence",level=0.95) # predict from the model, using your data frame

plot(data$mum.age, model4pred, xlab = 'Mum Age (yrs)', ylab = 'Model 4 Predicted mass values (g)', main = 'Predicted values of Model 4 vs Mother Age', xlim = c(0,12), pch=16, col="orange", cex=1)
matplot(data$mum.age,model4.pred2, type='l',lty=c(1,2,2),col='black')
```

I thought I would get a graph with three lines the main model output and then the confidence intervals.

see code in previous section

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What type of model is `model4`? Be sure to include all non-base R packages that you are using.